# How to clear directions on Angular google Maps

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps, google-directions-api

```
<agm-map
        [zoom]="mapConfig.zoom"  [styles]="mapConfig.styles" 
        [latitude]="currLate" [longitude]="currLongi"
        >
        <agm-direction *ngIf="path" 
        [origin]="path.origin" 
        [destination]="path.destination"
        [waypoints]="waypoints"
        ></agm-direction>
</agm-map>
```

This is my code for implementing directions using Angular Google maps.
I gave origin,destination and array of waypoints, the problem is that when i create new route, both old and new routes stays on the maps.
But I want to reset/clear the directions so that i can show only the new direction route on the map.

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you implement the directions, you'll have a DirectionsRenderer instance (from instantiating a new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer). To attach this to your map, you'll do something like

```
_directionsRenderer.setMap(this.map)
```

So to get rid of the directions, you'll need to "unset" the map. Best way to do this is:

```
_directionsRenderer.setMap(null)
```

Really, anywhere you have a setMap, any time things update you'll want to setMap(null) on it.